# App Debugging - What dictates how long my app stays in the background?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I've been debugging my app recently, and I noticed that when I background it, it does not stay in the background for very long at all. I've read that iOS usually decides how long an app gets to stay in the background, but I feel that the time mine is allowed is abnormally short - anywhere from a few minutes to a few seconds.

Is there anything I can do to increase the amount of time my app gets in the background or anything I can do to let iOS know I want my app to stay backgrounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple reasons your app is allowed to run in the background, I would refer to this document from apple for more insights https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the video at https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ on Multitasking. For the future of course.